# Read Text File in Stored Procedure

Tags: javascript, mongodb, stored-procedures

I want to use a stored procedure to update a table in mongoDB.  The data is in a CSV file and I want to access it with split.  I've done this any number of times in JavaScript with no problems. What I have for the start is:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var ForReading = 1;
var daFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\MyFolder\\myfile.dat",ForReading);
while (!daFile.AtEndOfStream)
{ 
    daLine = daFile.readLine();
    // do the stuff
}
```

But the command chokes on the ActiveXObject.  I'm guessing that mongo doesn't know from ActiveXObjects so what can I use instead to read the lines from the file?

Comment: Are you running this in Internet Explorer? The problem is that ActiveXObject is only available in IE

Comment: I'm trying to use MongoVue to store a JavaScript and run it from there.  It should be possible to do something like it from mongo.exe as well.  I know that ActiveXObject is available from outside of IE as I use it quite often to do this sort of thing from a JavaScript run at the OS level - write/save the script and double click the file.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ActiveXObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx) object is a Microsoft extension that is only supported in Internet Explorer, or applications that invoke the Internet Explorer JavaScript engine.

The JavaScript engine used by the `mongo` shell and MongoDB server (as at MongoDB 2.6) is the open source [V8 engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)).

MongoDB does not have the equivalent of "stored procedures" that can load and process text files on your server. You should instead be doing import operations from a client driver or application.

If you have a simple CSV file to import, a straightforward approach would be using [`mongoimport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/), which is included when you install the MongoDB shell and tools.

Assuming the first row of your CSV includes column headers, the command line would look similar to:

```
mongoimport --db my_db --collection mycoll --type csv --headerline < myfile.dat
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to use the dat file to add things to the existing entries.  The goal is to use one column of the dat file to find the matching entry in the table.  The the other columns of the dat file are added as a new and complex item to the existing entry.  That's why I need the JavaScript.